# CreateProcess Exception (kernel32.lib)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, win32-process

I am getting an exception when I run this code:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

CreateProcess(NULL, L"program.dat", NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

// Wait until child process exits.
WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

// Close process and thread handles. 
CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
```

I get the exception on WaitForSingleObject.

Thanks :)

Comment: You're not checking if `CreateProcess()` was actually able to create the process. I would recommend checking its return value and invoking `GetLastError()` if it is `FALSE`.

Comment: `program.dat` I don't think it will launch dat files like executables.

Comment: `CreateProcess` is for launching executables. It looks like you're trying to launch a non-executable, so you should use `ShellExecute` instead. Because of this my guess is that `CreateProcess` is failing. Check that the return value isn't zero, and if it is (ie it failed) call `GetLastError` to see why.

Comment: When I use ShellExecute, I get this error: http://qs.lc/81xt

Comment: This is my current code: http://qs.lc/wjj2; and this is the exception I get with current code: http://qs.lc/gehj

Comment: I have fixed the issue, thanks to 1st answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339186/createprocess-fails-with-an-access-violation?rq=1

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't find [CreateProcess fails with an access violation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339186/createprocess-fails-with-an-access-violation) which is the #1 hit for `CreateProcess access violation`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As clearly as much that can be stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx)::

> The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string. Therefore, **this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory** (such as a const variable or a **literal string**). **If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation**.

Yours `L"program.dat"` falls under this rule. Copy the string in some `WCHAR` variable and pass that instead.

Comment: Also revealed by the type of the argument: `LPTSTR` instead of `LPCTSTR`. The legacy conversion from `const char/wchar_t *` to `char/wchar_t*` strikes again!

Comment: @Downvoter:: Why man why? :-)

Answer (score 4):

I can reproduce the exception using your code. I think the problem is that the second arg to CreateProcess is an in/out one. The doc states:

> The system adds a terminating null character to the command-line string to separate the file name from the arguments. This divides the original string into two strings for internal processing.

See [CreateProcess function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx)

The second arg must NOT point to read-only memory.

Using the Visual Studio debugger and stepping in assembler code, the trap is indeed caused by the _CreateProcessInternal function in Kernel32 trying to write 0x to the end of L"program.dat", which, as a string constant, is in a "non writable" section.

Use below code:

```
wchar_t * pCommandLine = L"program.dat";
wchar_t CommandLine[ 64 ];
wcscpy( CommandLine,  pCommandLine );
CreateProcess(NULL, CommandLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

and the exception will vanish.

As for Creating a Child Process with "program.dat" ?!? That's another story.