# How to run a program when a service crashes in Windows in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, api, visual-c++

I would like to run another program when a service crashes. I know that I should use `SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS` and `ChangeServiceConfig2()` provided by Microsoft. But, I got stuck using them because I can not find any example of using these structure and function.

I would appreciate it if anyone can show me an example to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so hard.  You need something like this:

```
SC_ACTION sc_actions = { SC_ACTION_RUN_COMMAND, 0 };
TCHAR command [] = __T ("path/to/command");
SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS failure_actions =
    { INFINITE, NULL, command, 1, &sc_actions);
BOOL ok = ChangeServiceConfig2 (service_handle,
    SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS, &failure_actions);
```

Where, as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-changeserviceconfig2a) states, `service_handle` is obtained by a call to [OpenService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-openservice).

Comment: casting away `const` seems like a bad idea.  [Some Windows APIs actually do overwrite their input parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11339186/103167) so passing string literals to arguments not declared `LPC(T|W)STR` is not advisable.

Comment: @BenVoigt Quite right, what _was_ I thinking?  Edited, thank you.